# How to protect a submit form from

Tags: php, forms, google-chrome

In google chrome there is something called Inspect element,you access it by pressing f12 or rigth click Inspect element.

So i have a from

```
<form>
<textarea name="title" id="title" maxlength="120"/></textarea>
</form>
```

So now if use Inpect element and edit the page and change the maxlenght to 500 i can send data bigger than 120.So how can i make sure that the data is 120 even if the user edit the page with Inpect element

If i use javascript to chek the length still the user can edit the javascript as well

Comment: Or I could just inspect the form element and see the action attribute to see where the form data is being submitted and submit to it directly, passing it anything I want.  Or I could be on some old or really wacky browser that has a bug where the length attribute is ignored.  Listen to Călin, server-side verify *everything*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always check the submitted data server-side. Trust nothing the user submits.

[Off-topic] Also be careful not to allow any kind of injection (client scripts, SQL, anything that the server or another user's browser could accidentally execute)

Comment: Simple as that.  Never trust user data, never trust the browser.  It's actually so much easier to do a server-side verify than client-side attempts involving hashes and ciphers, etc.  Just check on the server to add the extra layer of security and integrity.

Answer (score 1):

> how can i make sure that the data is 120 even if the user edit the page with Inpect element

Verify it **on the server side** of course.

```
if (strlen($_POST['data']) > 120) // some error
```

not a big deal

Note the pronoun you have used.
"you" (assuming "we") can be used only for the server-side, of which you have a control.
While client side is "they" - this is someone's computer which you have not a slightest control of.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it reliably on the client side, what you pass out to the client is just a hint that the client due to bugs or malicious users could ignore freely.

What you need to do is hint to the client as you do to help well behaved clients, but always *validate the incoming data on the server*.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome's 'Inspect Element' Function is a great tool, but as you say it can manipulate pages and this has been referred to previously on apple and Microsoft as being an 'illegal hack'. There is no way to stop this. Try using inline validation.

Comment: Inspect Element is a godsend, as is Firebug. Anyone who knows how to use these tools (beyond "hey what's this thang do?") will also know how to send a POST request directly to the server.  And more than once I've hacked the DOM of a 3rd party site not to get the form to do something it wasn't supposed to do, but something it *was* supposed to do, but some screwy javascript broke the form flow (like  they hid the address field unless some other box was selected, but that box was inactive because the page was reloaded, or whatever).

Comment: I'm not saying it is not useful, I LOVE IT! but others do not :)